# Adding validators to fields in Django models.py

Tags: python, django, django-validation

I am using django.core.validators inside my models.py but I keep getting syntax error.

The piece of code involved is the following:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

class StepStart(models.Model):
    motor_type_choices = (                                                  
    ('1'),
    ('2'),
    ('3'),
    ('4'),
    ('5'),
    ('6'),
    )
    temp_start = models.IntegerField(                                       
        default=30,
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(90), MinValueValidator(10)]
    )
    level_start = models.IntegerField(                                     
        default=30,
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(150), MinValueValidator(10)]
    )
```

The error is a syntax error on the line of default=30.

I've checked on other posts here and the validation method I used seems okay.

Can someone point out the error please?

This is the error message I get in the command prompt:

```
line 65
default=30,
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks.

Comment: You forgot comma i think?

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
temp_start = models.IntegerField(                                       
        default=30
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(90), MinValueValidator(10)]
    )
    level_start = models.IntegerField(                                     
        default=30
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(150), MinValueValidator(10)]
    )
```

to this:

```
temp_start = models.IntegerField(                                       
        default=30,
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(90), MinValueValidator(10)]
    )
    level_start = models.IntegerField(                                     
        default=30,
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(150), MinValueValidator(10)]
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, I did add the commas as suggested but I stil get invalid syntax error on the same line. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @giulia is this the same error message you got before you inserted the commas also? just curious.

Comment: Try removing the default value all together from first field and see if error persists. If it does, then remove default value from both fields and see what happens. This will help you identify the source of the problem.

Comment: Hi. Yes it was the same error, which was solved very misteriuosly by removing all the default values. I have no idea about why - since I'm a complete beginner at Django - but that solved the issue. Thanks for your help!